# How to simplify this nested param include check?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails, I've got this checkbox tag, where the checked value should be true if an element is included in post array.

```
- checked = (params[:comments] && params[:comments][:pictures] && params[:comments][:pictures].include?(comment.id))
=check_box_tag "comments[pictures][]", comment.id, checked
```

The checked part looks very ugly. How to catch the error if params[:comments] or params[:comments][:pictures] is not set? I tried

```
- checked = (params[:comments][:pictures].include?(comment.id)) || false
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to install `simple_form` and use:

```
= simple_form_for @comment do |f|
  = f.association :pictures, :as => 'boolean'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could merge in a hash of default values, and then you are sure there's a params[:comments][:pictures] value (an empty array in this instance):

```
params = {:comments => {:pictures => []}}.merge(params)
checked = params[:comments][:pictures].include?(comment.id)
```

Comment: BTW That's code off the top of my head, please excuses typos or syntax errors - check the API for the use of .merge to make sure I got it the right way round ;-)